# what does "blur" mean in graphic design?

Tags: interface-design

I see our designers referring to blur on screens. what exactly are they referring to? These are transaction flows.

Answer (score 3):

It means the same thing it does in any other profession - out of focus, unclear, smeared.....

For web development, form input fields can use an `onBlur` event in javascript meaning the cursor is no longer active within the input field. So you would "blur" the field by making it non-active. -- this is the *only* thing I can think of which may be specific to the design profession.

So....  when you click an HTML form input, the browser/app fires a `focus` event because the input becomes active. When you leave that form field the browser/app fires a `blur` event because the field is no longer active. Essentially... Switch ON = focus, switch OFF = blur.

You can use these events to trigger *other* things, such as javascript, or Cascading Style Sheet (CSS) appearance changes.